# Magento 2: Can't select "categories" on cart pricerule

Tags: magento2.2, category-tree, price-rules

I have try to make a price rule in Magento 2. But I can't see the option "categories".

Someone know where I can activate it? Or did i do something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see category option once you select product attribute combination. By default it shows only cart/quote attribute. Once You select product attribute combination you will see another dropdown like below.[image]

Let me know in case further help needed.

Comment: welcome @Joost :)